# DateTime fields not displaying in Crystal Report (From SQL Server)

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a field within a table (SQL Server 2008 Database), that is of type DateTime, This field allows null values and in conclusion contains a few nulls as well as a few actual values, But as you can see from the pictures attached, none of these fields are showing (CR is acting as if all values are null). I have checked that the dataset i used to populate the report, contains the correct data, and it does. How can I go about resolving this problem?[image: Preview of generated report]

[image: Preview of report design]

```
    private void RefreshReport(frmReportScreen showForm)
    {
        dsReports dsData = new dsReports();

        rptDetailedReport rptDetailedReport = new rptDetailedReport();

        try
        {
            DataTable dtPrintReport = clsSqlData.SqlFillDataTable(strSQL, 1);
            if (dtPrintReport.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DataTableReader reader = new DataTableReader(dtPrintReport);
                dsData.Tables["dtDetailReport"].Load(reader);

                rptDetailedReport.SetDataSource(dsData);
                rptDetailedReport.SetParameterValue(0, dateTimePicker1.Value);
                rptDetailedReport.SetParameterValue(1, dateTimePicker2.Value);

                showForm.crvReportViewer.ReportSource = rptDetailedReport;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error loading the report : " + ex.Message, "Error Loading Report", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Reid sounds like a query issue or a mapping issue can you show relevant code.. can't make heads or tails out of that image it's too small for one thing... do you have anything like the following in your code `crystalReportViewer1.ParameterFields.Add(@DateParam);` please show your SQL command and how you are building and passing the parameters..

Comment: Hi, What code would you like to see? generation of the report? PS Not params, since i get the data from the database, not from user input

Comment: how are you getting the data from the database.. that's the code I was wanting to see

Comment: 'dsReports dsData = new dsReports();

            rptDetailedReport rptDetailedReport = new rptDetailedReport();

            try
            {
                DataTable dtPrintReport = clsSqlData.SqlFillDataTable(strSQL, 1);
                if (dtPrintReport.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    DataTableReader reader = new DataTableReader(dtPrintReport);
                    dsData.Tables["dtDetailReport"].Load(reader);

                    rptDetailedReport.SetDataSource(dsData);

                    showForm.crvReportViewer.ReportSource = rptDetailedReport;
    }'

Comment: if you are going to post the code please paste it in the original section up to where you asked the original question

Comment: So i have a dataset that i have created called dsReports, I dragged the table from my server explorer onto it. Then created a crystal report called rptDetailedReport and user the dataset as the datasource. Worked since i got the fields onto the report. Then set the report source etc... the sql text is fine since i didnt get a constraint exception.

Comment: please edit your question and paste the code in that section not here in the comments section..

Comment: There you go mate, my bad.

Comment: you are missing the `ParameterFieldName` for the fields that you want to assign the datetimePicker

Comment: Sure, but thats not the problem, since the dates that i get from the databsed (The ones that arent showing) are entirely different, infact, the datetimepickers' values show. Thats not the problem

Comment: now I understand what you are saying. so let me ask you this when you step thru the code.. are you getting any values when you hover over `dateTimePicker1.Value)` and `dateTimePicker2.Value)` if so, perhaps you need to `Cast` the value like this (string)dateTimePicker1.Value or do `dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2008 R2
CR 8.5

I had the problem of an sproc returning one smalldatetime, and two datetime values, would display only the smalldatetime - the others were displayed as blank, but upon examination, were actually just incredibly corrupt (e.g. year was "-471"). Changing those two to smalldatetime completely solved this.

However, there was another weirdness never explained: none of this was a problem when run in the designer, going to the exact same RPT file and database, and with the same user credentials. It only corrupted the datetime values when the report was run from the old VB app that had CR integrated as a COM object. We can't change the app (2013, and antiquated from the get-go).

My going-forward solution (for the time remaining for this app) will be to return dates as pre-formatted strings, to avoid any further date-datatype problems using this ancient software.